# Reference? filler: IRS, Rhind Papyrus, High-school algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, math-history

I believe something like this was included as a filler in one of the MAA journals many years ago. I am searching for the exact reference (for the filler, or an earlier source).

> Someone dies, and his will makes some bequests, then ends by saying
>   "after taxes are paid, any remaining money should be donated to
>   charity". Well, if charitible donations are tax-deductible, then the
>   amount of the donation effects the taxes. What to do? The I.R.S.
>   supposedly has a form where you do this computation, but it amounts
>   essentially to trial and error. In fact the problem can be solved by
>   high-school algebra. (Solution of a linear equation.) Or, not even
>   that: the problem can be solved using the "method of false position":
>   that method is described in the Rhind Papyrus, which dates from maybe
>   2650 B.C.
>
> And some people say the I.R.S. is behind the times...

[LINK](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=539593)

Comment: With apologies to the many great teachers everywhere, and none whatsoever to the IRS: "Those who can, do. Those who can't, teach. Those who can't teach, administrate."